# Who else was Voldemort afraid of?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

This question just came to my mind. We saw that Voldemort was afraid of Albus Dumbledore. Was he afraid of Aberforth too? Because we see that Aberforth was a powerful wizard.

So, whether he was afraid of Aberforth or not, who else was Voldemort afraid of?

Comment: Aberforth could cast a Patronus, which is an advanced spell, so that's certainly true. But otherwise he's portrayed as mediocre, in fact this question has  just made me realise how odd that is. Doge describes him as being not at all bookish or academically gifted and Albus once says (though possibly in jest and possibly even intending to maintain Aberforth's obscurity) that he's not entirely sure his brother can read! I wouldn't say that it's my impression that we see Aberforth was powerful?

Comment: Three Ds: Dumbledore, Death and Darkness.

Comment: @Au101 i remember that once Hermione told harry, just a powerful wizard who can do powerful patronus charm like Aberforth.

Comment: Why Voldemort doesnt kill Aberforth? while Aberforth is one of the order of the pheonix and brother of Albus, Voldemort could use it as advantage against Albus, or else he was scared from Aberforth too. and about education stuff, not all not well educated are idiots, some of them got a lot of talent in other things.

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi He probably saw Aberforth as nothing but beneath contempt, much like so many others. I wonder if he ever met Aberforth for that matter. He fooled Voldemort's Death Eaters with his Patronus but who cares? That doesn't mean much about his wizardry does it? Even Ron made the - rather ridiculous - statement that maybe his Patronus was the doe they had seen in the forest (and since Aberforth had just shown his to be a goat - a speciality or affinity of his being goats - Aberforth says he - Ron - could be a Death Eater with such foolishness).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the whole I would say nobody is almost certainly the answer. We are repeatedly told throughout the books that the accepted in-universe opinion is that Voldemort was only afraid of Dumbledore. For example Hagrid says:

> '[...] One o' the only safe places left was Hogwarts. Reckon Dumbledore's the only one You-Know-Who was afraid of. Didn't dare try takin' the school, not jus' then, anyway.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - p.45 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 4, *The Keeper of the Keys*

For me, perhaps the strongest indicator of this is the title of chapter 36 of *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*: *The Only One He Ever Feared*. To me this feels like Rowling establishing this as a fact and it certainly makes me doubt that you'll find other examples in canon.

However...

One could make a case for him being afraid of the baby Harry. He is surely dismissive of Harry's abilities and does not treat him as any kind of rival. He is arrogant with him and makes sport of him in their first encounter in the Graveyard in *The Goblet of Fire*.

However:

> *He pointed the wand very carefully into the boy's face: he wanted to see it happen, the destruction of this one, inexplicable danger.*
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - pp.281-2 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 17, *Bathilda's Secret*

Comment: The chapter title is the give away in the matter, yes. His hesitation in Deathly Hallows was just wisdom/care rather than fear by itself (he still thought himself superior). That's the same reason he had Nagini kill poor Severus rather than use the Elder Wand. Arrogance of course got rid of the hesitancy and it was to his ending once Nagini had been killed.

Answer (score 2):

## The only wizard he feared seemed to be Dumbledore.

McGonagall said that Dumbledore is the only one the Dark Lord feared. She would most likely know, and she tends to be precise and isn’t prone to either exaggeration or hyperbole.

> “I know you haven’t,’ said Professor McGonagall, sounding half-exasperated, half-admiring. ‘But you’re different. Everyone knows you’re the only one You-Know – oh, all right, *Voldemort* – was frightened of.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 1 (The Boy Who Lived)*</sup></sub>

Hagrid also says that Dumbledore was the only one the Dark Lord feared, but he has a tendency to overstate things because of his own emotions. McGonagall saying it seems more trustworthy, because she’s shown to be logical and accurate.

### He never seemed to fear Harry - though he wanted his threat eliminated.

The Dark Lord believed in the prophecy, so considered Harry a threat because he was the one foretold to have the power to defeat him. Because of that, he wanted to make sure Harry was destroyed, but he never thought of Harry himself as someone worth *fear*. Even when Harry had survived multiple attacks and two Killing Curses, the Dark Lord attributed it to his own errors.

> “Again, Voldemort looked up at the slowly revolving body as he went on, ‘I shall attend to the boy in person. There have been too many mistakes where Harry Potter is concerned. Some of them have been my own. That Potter lives is due more to my errors, than to his triumphs.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

He’s described as afraid a few times, like when he first lost his body, when he realized no Death Eaters were searching for him, and when he failed to get the Philosopher’s Stone. However, none of those times is he ever shown as afraid of Harry himself.

## He did fear other things, though - mainly things related to death.

Though he only feared one *wizard*, the Dark Lord did have other fears - mostly of death and things related to it, such as dead bodies. Dumbledore also says he fears darkness.

> “Not while they are merely drifting peacefully below us,’ said Dumbledore. ‘There is nothing to be feared from a body, Harry, any more than there is anything to be feared from the darkness. Lord Voldemort, who of course secretly fears both, disagrees. But once again he reveals his own lack of wisdom. It is the unknown we fear when we look upon death and darkness, nothing more.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 26 (The Cave)*</sup></sub>

From what Dumbledore says, it may also imply that the Dark Lord fears the unknown as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that some part of Voldemort did fear Harry otherwise he wouldn’t have acted on the prophecy. When Harry got older and kept defeating him or escaping his traps even if by luck it would make this worse. 
Voldemort might try to deny his rising fear but a part of him is like Ivan Drago at the end of Rocky 4. Wondering just what he has to do to beat this guy that just won’t go down. By the time of the final battle between them he is definitely afraid of Harry who has survived his worst attack again.